# math operations on currencies (crypto) stored in sqlite as bigint

Tags: java, sqlite, currency, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to store cryptocurrencies values inside a sqlite database.
I read that is not correct to store those values as float nor double because the loss of precision caused by the IEEE754.
For this reason I saved this values as biginteger in my database. (And I multiply or divide by 10^8 or 10^(-8) in my app before reading or storing the values).

```
create table Transactions
(
    id                INTEGER not null  primary key autoincrement unique,
    crypto_name         TEXT    not null,
    total_fiat_amount BIGINT default 0 not null,
    crypto_fiat_price   BIGINT default 0 not null,
    commission        BIGINT default 0 not null,
    date              BIGINT not null
);
```

But now I have a problem: Suppose I want to calculate the amount of coin using this formula:

```
SELECT "coin_name", ("total_fiat_amount"-"commission")/("crypto_fiat_price")) AS crypto_amount FROM Transactions GROUP BY "coin_name";
```

But the result is always wrong because is always in integer (the decimal part is always truncated and omitted). I need a real number, but without the loss of precision, because I need affordable results.

For a workaround I could cast to double or multiply for 1.0, but that's not what I want because doing so I think I will have wrong results in double! (and so I could have used double from the beginning).

Are there any viable solutions?
(Except avoid sql for this kind of calculations and doing the math in the app, because it's not a valid solution)

Comment: All the columns involved in the calculation have INTEGER affinity so SQLite performs integer division (by design). You can't change this, so multiply by 1.0

Comment: Ok but if I multiply by 1.0 I will obtain a double. So I could have wrong results due to the loss of precision... Or Am I wrong? So what's the advantage of not using double from the beginning?

Comment: There is no advantage for this case.

Comment: It looks very strange. This means that it's impossible to create a reliable cryptocurrency app using sqlite. If I can only store data as integers but I can't do divisions with my values or doing aggregate functions it would be crazy. It's hard to believe there is no solution, I think there are many android apps for crypto using sqlite. How can they work?

Comment: I don't know, but maybe they do such calculations at the application level and not with the database engine.

Comment: How many decimal digits of presicion do you need?

Comment: @forpas This is a possibility (except storing double values in the db) but it's very very inefficient, I hope to find a real solution

Comment: @dan1st I need 8 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: You could multiply it by 10^8 before running the division: `SELECT "coin_name", ("total_fiat_amount"-"commission")*100000000/("crypto_fiat_price")) AS crypto_amount FROM Transactions GROUP BY "coin_name";` if that does not overflow. With 32bit integers, it will overflow with around 20. With 64bit ints, you are safe.

Comment: @dan1st so I was thinking that for 8 decimal digits of precision:                            
MIN BIGINT NUMBER => -9223372036854775808
MAX BIGINT NUMBER =>  9223372036854775807

MIN CRYPTO NUMBER => -92233720367.99999999
MAX CRYPTO NUMBER =>  92233720367.99999999

Comment: @dan1st mulitplying here for 10^8 and not at the app level as I am doing is pointless and make no difference. The problem is that each number here is an integer so sqlite truncate the decimal part of the division and give me back an integer as result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to just multiply the divident instead of multiplying the result.

If both `total_fiat_amount-commission` and `crypto_fiat_price` are mononitery values with a maximum of two digits after the comma, you don't need to multiply both with 10^8 but only with 10^2.

In that case, the result would be accurate to 0 decimal points of precision after the comma.

If you want to have 8 decimal pieces of precision after the comma, you can multiply the divident with 10^8 before running the division.

If you store `total_fiat_amount`, `commission` and `crypto_fiat_price` in cents, you could use this:

```
SELECT "coin_name", (("total_fiat_amount"-"commission")*100000000)/("crypto_fiat_price")) AS crypto_amount FROM Transactions GROUP BY "coin_name";
```

This limits  `total_fiat_amount-commission` to the 64bit integer limit divided by 10^8 so you would get a maximum limit of `92233720368` (cents) for `total_fiat_amount-commission`.